# Finding short route in linked arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to get short route between multiple arrays with c#. I want to define start location and finish location. After that function must be calculate which arrays will use. for example my start location is "1" and finish location is "31".

```
public int[] route1= {**1**,**2**,3,4,5};
public int[] route2= {11,15,3,**7**,**2**};
public int[] route3= {10,9,12,17,8};
public int[] route4= {21,18,**7**,**24**,**31**};
```

i want this result:

```
public int[] resultroute={1,2,7,24,31};
```

and used routes are "route1,route2,route4"

i don't know where to start. Thank you.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: For these kind of challenges, try to break down the problem to its smallest parts. How do you find the solution with only 1 array with 2 elements? 2 arrays with 1 element each? 2 elements each? ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, you can use a graph-based approach. You can represent your routes as nodes in a graph and connect them based on the common elements. Then, you can use a graph traversal algorithm to find the shortest path between the start and finish locations while keeping track of the routes used. Here's how you can implement this in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class RouteGraph
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<int>> routeConnections = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    public void AddRoute(int[] route)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < route.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!routeConnections.ContainsKey(route[i]))
                routeConnections[route[i]] = new List<int>();

            routeConnections[route[i]].Add(route[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    public List<int> GetShortestRoute(int start, int finish, out List<int> usedRoutes)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> routesByNode = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
        queue.Enqueue(start);
        routesByNode[start] = new List<int>();

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            int current = queue.Dequeue();

            foreach (var next in routeConnections[current])
            {
                if (!routesByNode.ContainsKey(next))
                {
                    routesByNode[next] = new List<int>(routesByNode[current]);
                    routesByNode[next].Add(current);
                    queue.Enqueue(next);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!routesByNode.ContainsKey(finish))
        {
            usedRoutes = null;
            return null; // No path found
        }

        usedRoutes = routesByNode[finish].SelectMany(node => routeConnections[node]).Distinct().ToList();
        usedRoutes.Add(finish);
        return routesByNode[finish];
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RouteGraph routeGraph = new RouteGraph();

        int[] route1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] route2 = { 11, 15, 3, 7, 2 };
        int[] route3 = { 10, 9, 12, 17, 8 };
        int[] route4 = { 21, 18, 7, 24, 31 };

        routeGraph.AddRoute(route1);
        routeGraph.AddRoute(route2);
        routeGraph.AddRoute(route3);
        routeGraph.AddRoute(route4);

        int start = 1;
        int finish = 31;

        List<int> usedRoutes;
        List<int> shortestRoute = routeGraph.GetShortestRoute(start, finish, out usedRoutes);

        if (shortestRoute != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shortest route:");
            foreach (var node in shortestRoute)
            {
                Console.Write(node + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Used routes:");
            foreach (var route in usedRoutes)
            {
                Console.Write("route" + (usedRoutes.IndexOf(route) + 1) + " ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No path found between the start and finish locations.");
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the Route Graph class represents the graph of routes and their connections. The Get Shortest Route method uses a breadth-first search approach to find the shortest path between the start and finish locations. It also keeps track of the used routes along the way. Finally, the main program demonstrates how to use the Route Graph class to find the shortest route

Comment: thanks for your answer @syed-usama, but i got an error

`foreach (var next in routeConnections[current])`

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary;